# Redirect htaccess automatic

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web

initially I had the site up **/beta/**, and google me indexed pages, now I would like that when one goes up as
**http: //miosito.ext/beta/blabla** become automatically 
**http: //miosito.ext/blabla**

I tried `redirect /beta/^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ http://miosito.ext/^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$`
 but it does not work ...

Any idea how can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
RewriteRule   "^beta\/(.+)"  "http://miosito.ext/$1"  [R,L]
```

> Reference for Rewriting URL:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: Where does the `new.` part come from?

Comment: @MikeRockett i was looking at this page for reference http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html so new was there in url. I removed it from answer